# Why does SqlConnection use reference type when passed as parameter?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am writing following function that gets one SqlConnection parameter.

```
    private void doSomething(SqlConnection cnn)
    {
        //do something
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

I am calling this method as shown below:

```
    private void RnD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //line 1
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        //line 2
        cnn.ConnectionString = "my connection string";
        //line 3
        cnn.Open();
        //line 4
        doSomething(cnn);
        /* here cnn should be in open state, but it closes as soon as doSomething is done */
        //line 5
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Console.Write("open");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("closed");
        }
    }
```

doSomething function closes connection after it finishes its work. 
But it is going above my head that why cnn's state is closed at line 5 after call to doSomething function at line 4?
We all know that parameters in C# are passed by value by default. When cnn is being passed by value then why is it getting closed at line 5?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is: what is the value of a reference type? So what is the value of the variable _cnn_ in the _RnD_Load_ method? It is a value that represent the memory area where the instance of the SqlConnection exists. Now you pass this value to _doSomething_ and inside that method you have another variable (same name but it is a different variable) whose value is the same of the outside _cnn_. If you use this variable to change the memory area represented by the value then the caller variable sees the same changes because it looks at the same memory area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `reference types` and `value types` in C# sharp. All primitive types like `int`, `string`, `Datetime`,... are value types which means unless you use `ByRef` keyword they will be passed as value to a function. But unlike these types every other Objects that are instantiated from classes are reference types which always will be pass as a `ByRef` parameter. you may wonder why following code equals to false even though the values are the same! :

```
(new Person("John"))==(new Person("John")) // equals to false
```

Comment: Reference types are passed "by value", as references.  Conceptually like passing a pointer by value.  The variable `cnn` contains a reference.  That reference is passed by value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Here is a very good explanation: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what calling by value vs reference means.

When passed by value, the `doSomething()` method is still free to change the state of the object, and those changes will be reflected in `RnD_Load()` when it uses that object. What `doSomething()` *can't* do is say that `cnn` in `RnD_Load()` now points to a different object (or null).

If, however, you had passed `cnn` by reference (by adding the `ref` qualifier to the parameter), then `doSomethign()` could say `cnn = someNewSqlConnectionObject;` and `cnn` in `RnD_Load()` would now point to that new object.

Answer (score 0):

Passing reference type object is done by coping a pointer to that object. So you do not copy chunk of memory, you just copy pointer to same memory. It's like coping a shortcut to file instead of coping a file.